# Start python apscheduler at next full second

Tags: python, apscheduler

I've tested the APscheduler with the provieded example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import os

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


def tick():
    print('Tick! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=3)
    scheduler.start()
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

    try:
        # This is here to simulate application activity (which keeps the main thread alive).
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        # Not strictly necessary if daemonic mode is enabled but should be done if possible
        scheduler.shutdown()
```

The output:

```
Tick! The time is: 2020-09-14 00:56:23.225999
Tick! The time is: 2020-09-14 00:56:28.226864
...
```

What is the best way to start the scheduler at the next full second/the next full 10s/next full minute/... so the output is more readable?

Example output, when it starts at the next round second:

```
Tick! The time is: 2020-09-14 00:56:23.000000
Tick! The time is: 2020-09-14 00:56:28.000000
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the documentation, you could set a start-date:

https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/triggers/interval.html

```
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=3, 
                 start_date='2021-06-23 11:36:00', end_date='2021-06-23 11:37:00')
```